# Why my project's UI got altered and data is being not displayed on registering the handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, registerhelper

I have to use an if else conditional statement in handlebar. For that I have registered a registerHelper in app.js Following is my code:

```
var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars'); 
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//setting up the RegisterHelper
var hbsss = expressHbs.create({
  // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
  helpers: {
    last: function (num) { return (num+100); },
  }
});

app.engine('hbs', hbsss.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.locals.layout = false;



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

});

module.exports = app;
```

If I remove the line/code: " app.locals.layout = false;"
I get following error:
[image]

Before adding the registerhelpers and running the server the UI is working fine displaying as below:
[image]
[image]

After adding the registerhelpers and running the server the UI got changed and content is also not displaying as below:
[image]

[image]